# Correct configuration for selenium server (docker)

Tags: selenium, docker

I'm trying to run a selenium/chrome server on my ubuntu server:

```
$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.4.0-chromium
```

In the logs of this docker container I see the following. So I think the configuration is wrong - as there is platform windows set for example...
I also don't need opera, safari or internet explorer - so I don't understand those lines...

```
11:58:53.364 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown'
11:58:53.407 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-05-16 11:58:54.732:INFO::main: Logging initialized @14874ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
11:58:56.886 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
11:58:56.888 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
11:58:56.889 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
11:58:56.890 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
11:58:56.892 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
11:58:56.893 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
11:58:56.896 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
2017-05-16 11:58:58.120:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
2017-05-16 11:58:58.887:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@14acaea5{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-05-16 11:58:59.851:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@7bbdf808{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-05-16 11:58:59.865:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @20008ms
11:58:59.865 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are Selenium trying to figure out what *capabilities* is has available. Your Selenium Docker container is considered a Linux OS. IE and Edge are Windows-only, and Safari runs on MacOS. Opera isn't installed, so there is no Opera driver available to Selenium.

Notice you are running the Chrome standalone, and there is no mention of Chrome in the log. That's a good thing.

Comment: So, this is the normal thing and I don't have to do anything, right? No need for doing any configuration at this point? Thought about set some things to avoid those messages...

Comment: Try using the Selenium container and find out. The same `docker run` command creates a functional Selenium container with Chrome driver installed for me. The message appear to be normal and nothing to worry about.